# How to reuse the old notification token as new token in firebase push notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

When an android app is reinstalled then the notification token that is generated by firebase is changed. So if any user subscribed to any groups then after reinstalling the app he/she does not get any push notification. Is there any way to reuse the same notification token after reinstallation of the app. Or is there any way to override the old notification token stored in various nodes when the user reinstall the app?

Answer (score 0):

No, the token is not reusable.  You should instead be storing user preferences in a centralized location so that the app can re-subscribe to any topics.